# StringTransform to sanitize strings in Swift

Tags: swift, string, foundation, icu

I'm attempting to sanitize a string in Swift using a single `StringTransform`.

I'm using this example string: `"Mom's \t Famous \"Ćevapčići\"!"`

And the expected result is: `"moms-famous-cevapcici"`

So far, I've been able to achieve this using a combination of `StringTransform` and `NSRegularExpression`:

```swift
"Mom's \t Famous \"Ćevapčići\"!"

    .applyingTransform(StringTransform("Latin-ASCII; Lower; [:Punctuation:] Remove;"))?

     // produces: Optional("moms famous\tcevapcici")

    .replacingMatches(
        by: try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "[^a-z0-9]+", options: []), 
        withTemplate: "-"
    )
    
    // produces: Optional("moms-famous-cevapcici")
```

Is there a way to do this using only `StringTransform`?

So far, I've only figured out how to remove certain characters, but not replace them. Eg.:

```swift
StringTransform("Latin-ASCII; Lower; [:Punctuation:] Remove; [^a-z0-9] Remove;")
```

The above transform produces `"momsfamouscevapcici"`.

I'd also like to avoid this result: `moms---famous-cevapcici`. Ideally, this transform could replace several consecutive characters with one dash.

Comment: It can be done with ICU transforms with custom rules, but `StringTransform` doesn't support custom rules :(

Comment: That's good to know. Thanks, @Sweeper